# Progress circle in Apple devics wihile installing mobile apps

Tags: swift, mobile-application

I am developing an enterprise application which is similar to apple appstore for my company. In this I have a requirement to implement the circular downloading progress image same as that which appear when we download or update any app from appstore. How can this be implemented using Swift language.
Any suggestion will be really helpful..

For more info plz have a look on this [image]

Comment: You can find from cocoascontrol.Use this link for reference https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress and https://github.com/PavelKatunin/DownloadButton

Comment: :- Glad i can help u.

Answer (score 0):

```
`JPCActivityIndicatorButton` is working fine in   `Xcode 8.3` `swift 3.x`
```

Useful case ->

```
   case Names.Spinning:
        activityIndicator.transitionSavedState(Names.ProgressBar)
    case Names.ProgressBar:
                activityIndicator.transitionSavedState(Names.Paused)
```

[image: dont't forget to add framework to your project]

Code-Details [JPActivityIndicatorButton](https://github.com/jpchmura/JPCActivityIndicatorButton)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar task and just managed to implement this today. I think the easiest way is to enhance current UI so that you only have to work on the part that deals with the progress circle.

In my case, I created a new class called "UIButtonEnhanced", which is a subclass of UIButton.

Please note that in your interface builder, you should first change the button's class into "UIButtonEnhanced", then create the outlet.

```
enum DownloadStatus {
    case remote
    case downloading
    case paused
    case resumed
    case success
}
    // MARK: extension is not ideal, a better solution should be a subclass of UIButton
class UIButtonEnhanced: UIButton {
    var progress: Float = 0 {
        didSet {
            circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(self.progress)
        }
    }

    var circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    public func drawCircle() {
        let x: CGFloat = 0.0
        let y: CGFloat = 0.0
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: self.frame.height, height: self.frame.height), cornerRadius: self.frame.height / 2).cgPath
        circleShape.path = circlePath
        circleShape.lineWidth = 3
        circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        circleShape.strokeStart = 0
        circleShape.strokeEnd = 0
        circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
    }

    // MARK: - Update the download status
    var status: DownloadStatus = .remote {
        didSet{
            var buttonImageName = ""
            switch self.status {
            case .remote:
                buttonImageName = "DownloadButton"
            case .downloading:
                buttonImageName = "PauseButton"
            case .success:
                buttonImageName = "DeleteButton"
            case .paused:
                buttonImageName = "DownloadButton"
            case .resumed:
                buttonImageName = "PauseButton"
            }
            self.setImage(UIImage(named: buttonImageName), for: .normal)
        }
    }
    }
```

In your viewController, you can create the circle with the following code:

```
    yourButton.drawCircle()
```

Then when your download progress changes, use this code:

```
    yourButton.progress = 0.5
```

When your download status changes, use this code:

```
    yourButton.status = .success
```